# How to implement a tss2 API in C or C++ to use funktions within code

Tags: c++, api, cryptography, tss

I am completely new to API programming, hence we never used it at university and nobody told us how to do this.

I have the problem, that i want to get random numbers from my TPM 2.0 module within a C++ programm and parse them to an cryptographic function like McEliece through the tss API.

I know that it must be somehow possible to use the command "tpm2_getrandom" within the code, which i also use in terminal to get random bytes, if the API is implemented.

I tried to copy the whole library in my working directory and include the headers of the needed functions, but it didn't work.

Now i really have no idea how to do this, the API descriptions at the official github page are quite confusing to me and not intuitive. They seem to be written for people who have at least a clue how APIs work and how to implement them and who are familar in cryptographic functions pragramming.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: You have to follow the instructions on the github page (I assume you mean [this](https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tools/blob/master/doc/INSTALL.md)). There are no short cuts. If the tools and technolgies are new to you then you have to learn how to use them. Unfortunately this isn't the right forum to learn about this kind of topic from scratch.

Comment: If you have specific questions about particular problems then we can help. Its just open ended questions don't work very well on a Q and A forum.

Comment: `git`, `configure`, `make` and package managers are all standard tools for building and installing software. Whole books have been written on each of these tools. It takes a while to get the experience necessary to use these tools successfully.

Comment: Thx guys, i'll try following the instructions on the github page. Looks like this problem is to specific and there is no other way, than studying the API itself.